# Html button that can redirect to your app or app store

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have two buttons but when viewing 9gag, they were able to group the two buttons into one. I was wondering how can I possibly do that.

[image]

First Button (which opens my app directly)

```
<a href="urlschemetest2://testurl.com"> Use The App</a>
```

Second button (which gives the option to download directly to playstore.

```
<a href="http://play.google.com?id=...."> Download Here</a>
```

May I ask how can I make it so that I have one button. If clicked on and the app is installed, it'll go to the app, otherwise go to the app store.

Comment: @LeeTaylor how is that relevant?

Comment: @gilbert-v Misread the question

Comment: I am guessing here but I think there are apps which intercept certain URLs on a mobile OS and they can offer to open them in the app instead. For example, if there is a link to an instagram post and you have instagram installed, your website doesn't have to do anything. The app will intercept it. That's how even if you get a link in a text message, it can open in an app.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`window.navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator) object to attempt to detect what OS the client is running, then change the `href` to point to the relevant URL.

If you're curious, you might learn more by typing `navigator` into your browser console and exploring its properties. `navigator.platform` seems like it could be useful.